# PHP Deprecated: Methods with the same name

Tags: php

I am getting an error saying

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; TSStatus has a deprecated constructor in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache24\htdocs\viewer\modules\tsstatus\tsstatus.php on line 10

class TSStatus is line 10 plus at the bottom TSStatus shows

```
class TSStatus
{
    private $_host;
    private $_queryPort;
    private $_serverDatas;
    private $_channelDatas;
    private $_userDatas;
    private $_serverGroupFlags;
    private $_channelGroupFlags;
    private $_login;
    private $_password;
    private $_cacheFile;
    private $_cacheTime;
    private $_channelList;
    private $_useCommand;
    private $_javascriptName;
    private $_socket;

    public $imagePath;
    public $showNicknameBox;
    public $timeout;
    public $hideEmptyChannels;
    public $hideParentChannels;

    public function TSStatus($host, $queryPort)

    ...
}
```

Comment: So use the proper `public function __construct($host, $queryPort)` constructor in your code, as the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) tells you to do

Comment: Or public static self::. But mark is right. Construct is better.

Comment: Don't use PHP 4 style constructors. From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php), *PHP 4 style constructors (methods that have the same name as the class they are defined in) are deprecated, and will be removed in the future*.

Comment: Using FPDF with the file "pdf_parser.php". Line 101 has "function pdf_parser($filename)". Changing this to "function __construct($filename)" and it no longer works. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

As mentioned in the error, [the official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) and the comments:

Replace

```
public function TSStatus($host, $queryPort)
```

with

```
public function __construct($host, $queryPort)
```

Comment: Because I was wondering:
Yes, it's a drop-in-replacement. Nothing else to do but just rename it.

Comment: Will the functionality got disturbed if I do that change?

Comment: @AminahNuraini No (see first comment)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it's still working on PHP 7.4, it just prints deprecated message. I tried `__construct` on PHP5 and it alrdy works, so it's all good and fun.

Comment: You failed to mention that calls to the constructor need to be changed to "parent::__construct();"

Comment: Helpful: https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php4-constructors-php7.htm

Answer (score 0):

I was getting warnings, about this problem, and now it start to work. At first it was:

```
function Smarty()
{
  $this->assign('SCRIPT_NAME', isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
                : @$GLOBALS['HTTP_SERVER_VARS']['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

But I made this way:

```
function _construct()
    {
      $this->assign('SCRIPT_NAME', isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
                    : @$GLOBALS['HTTP_SERVER_VARS']['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Now I've stoped getting warnings and the script is working well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).