# fpdf 1.81 with php-7 running on linux

Tags: linux, codeigniter, fpdf, php-7.1

I develop an application and the generation of the PDF on Windows walks (works) very well. Yesterday I wanted to test my application on Linux, I use Lamp who turns on PHP 7. When I launch the generation of the PDF here is the message that I obtain:

> **Severity: 8192
>
> Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; FPDF has a deprecated
>   constructor
>
> Filename: php/fpdf.php
>
> Line Num

ber: 12**

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: The message is clear: php is changing the way of declaring class constructors. Get a new version of your library with the appropriate fix.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100373/php-deprecated-methods-with-the-same-name

Comment: Thanks, but I have the latest version of FPDF Libraty and I have the good systaxe of the constructor : **function __construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $size='A4'){} **. On Windows the code work very well with PHP 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got your answer...

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

// instead of "$doc = new PDF();" use "$doc = new FPDF();"

$doc = new FPDF('P', 'mm', array(100,150));
$doc -> AddPage();
$doc -> SetFont('Arial','B', 16);
$doc -> MultiCell(40,10, 'hello word!');
$doc -> OutPut('F', 'folio.pdf');
```