# PHP Constructor causes "Call to undefined method"

Tags: php, constructor

Have been using FPDF successfully for many years.
Upon upgrading to PHP7, I was informed **methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of php**.

Answers to question [37100373](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100373/php-deprecated-methods-with-the-same-name) say to simply change the function name to `__construct`.

I made this change in a filed called "pdf_parser.php" (FPDI - Version 1.4.4 by Jan Slabon)

```
function pdf_parser($filename) {
```

Changed to:

```
function __construct($filename) {
```

Making this change causes this error:

**Call to undefined method pdf_parser::pdf_parser() in /usr/www/users/w6wehfc9/course/fpdf/fpdi_pdf_parser.php on line 74**

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fpdi_pdf_parser.php change

```
function fpdi_pdf_parser($filename, &$fpdi)
```

to

```
function __construct($filename, &$fpdi)
```

and in fpdi_pdf_parser.php change

```
parent::pdf_parser($filename);
```

to

```
parent::__construct($filename);
```