# How to convert HTML into PDF using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to convert an HTML file into PDF and save it.
For this i am using mpdf. When I try to run my code it shows some error which is

> mPDF error Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; m_pdf has a deprecated constructor

i am attaching my code below,

```
   public function create_pdf()

   {
     include('public/pdf/MPDF_6_0/mpdf60/mpdf.php');

     $localname="test";

     $type="next";

     $amount=10;

     $unqid=1234;



     $html='<p style="color:red;">'. $localname . ' ' . $type. '  Thanks for the payment of Rs ' .$amount. ' your receipt no is ' .$unqid;

    $mpdf = new mPDF($html);

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

    $t=time();

   $file=$t.'receipt.pdf';

     $mpdf->Output('public/uploads/receipt'.
      $file, 'F');

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Deprecated: Methods with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100373/php-deprecated-methods-with-the-same-name)

Comment: in my case my class name and function name are diiferent

Comment: Yes, obviously, but the error is the same. Read the solution and apply it to your problem.

Comment: how can i apply that into my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this package, it contains a lot of options and features:
https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf